# How do I use relative paths with the webdriver.Navigate().GotoUrl()?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("/") sets the location to "/" instead of "http://www.domain.com/"

another example would be

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("/view1") sets the location to "/view1" instead of "http://www.domain.com/view1"

Either example would cause the browser to return with address isn't valid.

Comment: testing routes. a relative path from the root is shorter than localhost/whatever and its less to type too. I've made the root itself a global constant, but its still a pain.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a Java URI to calculate a path relative to the current uri or domain:

```java
import java.net.URI;

driver.get("http://example.org/one/");

// http://example.org/one/two/
driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("two/").toString());

// http://example.org/one/two/three/?x=1
driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("three/?x=1").toString());

// http://example.org/one/two/three/four/?y=2
driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("./four/?y=2").toString());

// http://example.org/one/two/three/five/
driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("../five/").toString());

// http://example.org/six
driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("/six").toString());
```

If you're able to calculate the url without using getCurrentUrl(), it might make your code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

The solution now is to use:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToRelativePath("/view1");
```

and you will be navigated within the same domain.

**UPDATE:**
This was valid in Selenium WebDriver 2.42 but does not seem to be listed in 3.1 the solution would be

`driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl + "/view1")`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest way to navigate to a specific url when they all have the same domain:

```
private String baseUrl = "http://www.domain.com/";

[...]

driver.get(baseUrl + "url");
```

driver.get(String url) is equivalent to driver.navigate().to(String url).